# Assign default values using FileNode class in new C++ OpenCV API

Tags: c++, opencv

I was reading [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html) article on using new API for writing XML/YAML using OpenCV.

I was wondering how to assign **default values** if trying to read a value from FileNode object fails.

For example, in the older API I would write:

```
float somevalue =  cvReadRealByName(FileStorage_object, FileNode_object,"alpha", 1.0);
// above value returns 1.0 to variable "somevalue" if cvReadRealByName fails.
```

Now, I'm trying to the above using the FileNode class using the newer API:

```
float somevalue = (float)filenode_object["alpha"];
```

In the above statement, I can't specify default values if above method fails. Is there a easier way of doing this?

Can I do the above instead of using filenode_object.empty()?

Comment: read point 5 of the article that you linked, there is the answer...
`if(node.empty())
    x = default_value;
else
    x.read(node);`

Comment: I figure it. Thanks. But, older API was easier as I could in one line specify everything that I needed.

Comment: Yup, I don't like this syntax too